# What is the source of the belief that the seventh son of a seventh son is a clairvoyant?

Tags: myth-identification, folklore

The Iron Maiden song *Seventh Son of a Seventh Son* was inspired - according to Steve Harris - by the folklore belief that the seventh son of a seventh son has clairvoyant powers:

> “I just had a thought: ‘I wonder if she could foresee her own death?’” stated Steve Harris, in 2013’s Maiden England ’88 documentary. “Who knows? So I started off with that sort of idea. I wrote The Clairvoyant and then went to Bruce with it and basically he said, ‘Yeah, it’s a great idea!’ I started then having an idea for a song, Seventh Son Of A Seventh Son, because supposedly if you were born the seventh son of a seventh son you had the powers of a clairvoyant. So I had those two ideas and Bruce went, ‘You know what? We should do a concept album about this…’”
>
> <sub>Source: [How Seventh Son Of A Seventh Son lifted Iron Maiden to heavy metal immortality](https://www.loudersound.com/features/how-seventh-son-of-a-seventh-son-lifted-iron-maiden-to-heavy-metal-immortality). Dom Lawson. Metal Hammer.</sub>

Wikipedia [points to Ireland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventh_son_of_a_seventh_son#Ireland) as the source of the belief that the seventh son of a seventh son has healing powers, something that is mentioned in the song:

> Here the birth from an unbroken line
>   Born the healer the seventh, his time
>   Unknowingly blessed and as his life unfolds
>   Slowly unveiling the power he holds
>
> ...
>
> Today is born the seventh one
>   Born of woman the seventh son
>   And he in turn of a seventh son
>   He has the power to heal
>   He has the gift of the second sight
>   He is the chosen one
>   So it shall be written
>   So it shall be done

However, I wasn't able to find where the belief that the seventh son of a seventh son has "the gift of the second sight" comes from.

Help?

Comment: Didn't they take it from Orson Scott Cards novel?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventh_Son_(novel)

Comment: @Tom The song was partly inspired by the novel, yes. Are you saying that Orson Scott Card added clairvoyance to the long list of powers attributed to seventh sons of a seventh son?

Comment: @Tom This is much older than Orson Scott Card.

Comment: For example, the Willie Dixon blues song "[The Seventh Son](https://youtu.be/vaDHse7LDA0)" shows that this was already in popular folklore (_Well, I can tell your future/Before it come to pass/And I can do things for you/That make your heart feel glad/Look in the skies/And predict the rain/I can tell when a woman/Got another man_).....

Answer (score 1):

The Chambers Book of Days (1864) has a [passage](http://www.thebookofdays.com/months/jan/26.htm#SEVENTH%20SONS%20AND%20THEIR%20SEVENTH%20SONS) about seventh sons and it's [also referenced](http://www.sacred-texts.com/wmn/fow/fow28.htm) in Folk-Lore of Women(1906, and misleading title, it's very Victorian in its attitudes, as sacred-texts says on their index). It's an old superstition, obviously well entrenched by the mid-1800s, but the only real 'source' I've found is general stuff about the number seven being important across multiple cultures, etc etc.

HOWEVER I did some digging, and found an [apocryphal Bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testaments_of_the_Twelve_Patriarchs) verse, which seems to me a better source for something like this than most. Namely, [Testament of Dan](https://www.sacred-texts.com/bib/fbe/fbe285.htm) which is about anger, and [Fourth Book of Maccabees](https://www.sacred-texts.com/bib/fbe/fbe255.htm), which has a lot of sevens in it. Seven brothers, sevenfold companionship, seven days of creation, 'seven-towered right Reason', a lot of emphasis is put on the number. As for the clairvoyancy part,

> Blockquote 11 And then standing on the brink of death he said, 'I am no renegade to the witness borne by my brethren.
>   12 And I call upon the God of my fathers to be merciful unto my nation.
>   13 And thee will he Punish both in this present life and after that thou art dead.'
>   14 And with this prayer he cast himself into the red-hot brazier, and so gave up the ghost.

I think this might be the closest we have to a source for this. It's vague and a bit of a stretch, but it's suitably ancient, and frankly over a few centuries even a little thing can get pulled out of proportion, so a little pseudo-prophecy before a self-sacrifice that's played as being noble isn't terribly unreasonable.

Comment: 4 Maccabees has 7 sons (and naturally the last one is the 7th), but not 7th son of a 7th son. I'm not sure how the speech is pertinent; all of the other sons from first to sixth also had a speech